# Is $(-1)^{ab} = (-1)^{ba}$ true? => $(-1)^{ab} = ((-1)^a )^b$ is true?

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation

In general we know $A^{bc} = A^{cb}$ for integer $A$. 
I want to extend this to the case $A=-1$.

For integers $a,b$ I guess the above relation holds, 
\begin{align}
(-1)^{2\cdot3} = ((-1)^2)^3 = 1 = ((-1)^3)^2
.\end{align}

But if we include the fraction

\begin{align}
(-1)^{-\frac{1}{2}} &= ((-1)^{-1})^{\frac{1}{2}} = (-1)^{\frac{1}{2}} = i \\
&= ((-1)^{\frac{1}{2}})^{-1}=\frac{1}{i} = -i
\end{align}
this does not hold any more.

Is something wrong with my computation?

Comment: The problem here is that complex powers with non-integer exponent are ill-defined.

Comment: $-1$ is an integer for starters, second powers are not commutative for non-integer exponents.

Comment: On base of what do you say $(-1)^{\frac12}=i$? Why not $(-1)^{\frac12}=-i$? We have $i^2=-1=(-i)^2$.

Comment: Your title doesn't match the question. Obviously, $ab=ba$.

Comment: But can we say mod function make it hold true?? As integers are also mods??

Comment: @ArchisWelankar Well, similar statement about absolute values holds, but that's not a good way to put it.

Comment: If we do not stick to principal roots then we have $(-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}=\pm i$, then the results holds atleast for the example you have given

Comment: Also have a look at [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/847404/75923).

Comment: @ArchisWelankar: what the hell do you mean ?

Comment: What i mean its just finding out$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ not much than that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In complex numbers, 
$$(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$$ doesn't hold. You just found a counterexample.

This is due to the $2k\pi$ undeterminacy of the argument. When you take the square root, it becomes a $k\pi$ i.e. a sign indeterminacy.

Comment: Please explain this downvote.

Comment: @Arthur: I should have added "in general".

Answer (score 1):

Of course $(-1)^{ab} = (-1)^{ba}$, since multiplication is commutative. (No matter how you define exponentiation for complex numbers: fixed branch or multivalued.)

What **isn't true** is that $(-1)^{ab} = ((-1)^a)^b$ in general. This has been asked and answered many times on this site.

For similar questions, see for example

- [Why $\sqrt{-1 \times {-1}} \neq \sqrt{-1}^2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438)
- [Why $\sqrt{-1 \times -1} \neq \sqrt{-1}^2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49169)
- [math fallacy problem: $-1= (-1)^3 = (-1)^{6/2} = \sqrt{(-1)^6}= 1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/472227)
- [A basic question about exponentiation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1363354)
- [How to find complex numbers $z,\lambda,\mu$ such that $(z^\lambda)^\mu\neq z^{\lambda\mu}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104744)

just to mention a few.

Answer (score 1):

For complex number $z$ and integer $a$, $z^a$ is defined and equals $z*z*...*z$ ($a$ times) or ${1\over z}*{1\over z}*...*{1\over z}$ ($-a$ times) for negative $a$.

For *rational* $a={p \over q}$, $z^a$ can be said to have $q$ values, with one value called "main" or *principal* value. For rational $a,b$, $(z^a)^b$ and $(z^b)^a$ have the same set of values, but may have different principal values. In your case (simplifying things a bit):
$$((-1)^{-1})^{1 \over 2} = (-1)^{1 \over 2} = \{i, -i\} \\
((-1)^{1 \over 2})^{-1} = (\{i, -i\})^{-1} = \{-i, i\}$$

When $a$ is irrational, $z^a$ is usually said to be undefined (one could say it has infinitely many values).

Comment: Nicely explained.